# Open plink as default shell in conemu

Tags: conemu

To connect to remote servers I use putty inside conemu which does not allow splitted consoles.

Then I used plink.exe in conemu, got the split screens but pressing ^c two or more times returns back to command prompt (in putty the remote system is still connected).

I was wondering if there is a way around this, all I need is to use splitted screens to connect to remote systems and remain connected even if ^c is pressed.

I am trying to split screen and run plink as defualt shell in the newly spllited window, so far no luck.

Comment: Report Ctrl+C plink's problem to PuTTY author. Also, you may run putty in splits.

Comment: @Maximus, please guide how putty can be run in splits. using -new_console opens a new tab running putty in a child gui which does not allow splitting.

Comment: How? Just run it, nothing special. https://conemu.github.io/en/SplitScreen.html But running real console applications is preferable in ConEmu. So, report bugs to their authors.

Comment: Thank you very much @Maximus for the guidance,  the :s did the trick,